# MYSQL: WHERE NOT LIKE '%(SELECT column_name FROM table_name)%'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i try to find %column_name% from another table_name i see the result
but he seems to ignore the %%

Why it does not work for me?

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE NOT LIKE '%(SELECT column_name FROM table_name)%'
```

thanks,
Apologies if I do not act according to the rules, this is my first question.

Comment: `WHERE WHAT NOT LIKE`? What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: This will find column names that dont begin with (Select column_name etc is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name WHERE NOT LIKE (SELECT CONCAT('%', column_name, '%') FROM table_name)
```

You can't just include a query in a string, so put the wildcards next to the column name in a query and return that to the NOT LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name T
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT column_name from other_table O
                   WHERE O.column_name LIKE CONCAT('%',T.column_name,'%')
                 )
```